# Не получается подключить скрипты и стили к своей теме Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Сайт делаю на локальном сервере, использую MAMP. В файле своей темы добавил functions.php и прописал в нём функцию:

```
<?php 
function add_scripts_and_styles() {
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', array(), null, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'main',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array('jquery'), null, true );

wp_enqueue_style( 'fontello', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/fontello.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('fontello'));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'add_scripts_and_styles');
?>
```

В инспекторе страницы файлы не отображаются, ошибок по стилям и скриптам не вылазит. Структура документа такая: папка assets - в ней все стили, скрипты, картинки и т.д. functions.php находится в корне папки темы, там же где и index.php. В чём моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Обычно в файле темы выделяют специальные файлы для шапки сайта и подвала.
`header.php` и `footer.php`, а в них происходит вызов подключаемых объектов сайта -
`<?php wp_head(); ?>` `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` куда собственно WP и делает вывод подключаемых стилей. Возможно вы их забыли прописать...

Comment: Отдельные файлы под header и footer не создавал, но в index.php, где у меня сама html структура они прописаны в head и перед закрывающимся body соответсвенно

Comment: Возможно проблему находит VScode, пишет, что не найдено среду разработки php, собственно, я ёё и не устанавливал на устройство, учитывая, что в MAMP заложен свой php. Может ли быть в этом проблема?

Comment: Врядли... я бы начинал с малого. 1) Работает ли вообще WP, Если - да то проблема в теме. 2) Создал бы полностью пустую тему только необходимые файлы и подключал бы файлы по одному. jQuery и так идет по умолчанию в WP, если вы не отключали, то он и так подтянется повторно подключать не надо.